# Is it possible for a variable to be both true and false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My codes are down here and I get both

> here I am in IF
>   here I am in ELSE

How is that possible?

```
public class BGMusic : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static BGMusic instance;

    void Awake () 
    {
        if (instance) 
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
            print ("here I am in IF");
        } 
        else 
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            instance = this;
            print ("here I am in ELSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does that even compile?

Comment: you care calling Awake multiple times and in one case instance is defined and in another it's not.

Comment: @Aominè Strangely, it does compile on Unity. It has a lot of weird hacks.

Comment: Awake() called twice? First when instance is null and then when it isn't?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see... seems strange anyway.

Comment: I think Phil and scrappedcola are right...

Comment: `Awake()` is called by Unity, you don't call it explicitly. I'd assume the problem is that there're two `GameObject`s with `BGMusic` assigned, or that the OP assigned `BGMusic` twice to the same `GameObject`.

Comment: Thanks Camilo you are right. BGMusic is assigned two object by mistake. Thanks.

Comment: multithreading race conditions?

Comment: Quantum C# hasn't come out...yet.

Comment: @InBetween - *Cool* comment.

Comment: @InBetween actually it has! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-writeaquantumprogram?view=qsharp-preview

Comment: Which comes first in the log, the else or the if? Did you put the order in backwards of the log when posting your question?

Comment: @MistyK lol, good find! Didn’t know about that.

Comment: @InBetween - Compile option. CSC <filename> -spooky

Comment: Print the name of the game object so you can see who it is. Considering, they would have different names...

Answer (score 1):

You likely multiple game objects with a BGMusic attached or a single game object with multiple BGMusic attached.. The first instance that is processed goes in to the else, any other instanances of BGMusic attached to objects will go in to the if.

Because you get one else and one if that leads me to believe you have two instances of BGMusic attached to objects in your scene.